# C# HttpClient - get data size used for request

Tags: c#, .net-8.0

I am sending out continuous HTTP requests to an API, but want to stop when roughly x amount of data has been used, as a protection measure. How can I get the HTTP request size (before decompression) so I can keep track of this information using `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` or some equivalent standard .net class?

Comment: What you ask is called `rate limiting`. There are a lot of ways to do this. There's even an article [Rate limit an HTTP handler in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/http-ratelimiter) in the docs that shows one way to do this

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am not so sure it is exactly rate limiting, I do not care about how often the resource is accessed, I care about total bandwidth usage. Sort of like how you might set total network usage limits on your phone so you don't exceed your data plan. The article you linked to only shows how to rate limit based on number of requests within timeframe

Comment: That's not what you asked. Bandwidth is the data used over time - that's the definition of the term.